# What would happen if an unstoppable force hits an immovable object?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, acceleration, kinematics

I realize that the question a rather large paradox, but I do wonder if such a thing were true what would happen, assuming that neither of these "objects" can be destroyed by each other?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKc5kgPVrA

Comment: Well, unless there is to be a contradiction, here is one way that this statement might be true. The unstoppable passes through the immovable (e.g. neutrinos are pretty near to unstoppable). Maybe there are others, but mostly this statement is simply held to be a contradiction.

Comment: Even now, I perceive this question as a pun. In that case, [I know what happens](http://youtu.be/5oPsvq81n2A?t=1m30s) ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In reality this "paradox" is just basic logic. If you say that there exists an unstoppable object, you are also assuming that there can be no unmovable objects (otherwise, how would your unstoppable object be unstoppable). For the next part of the riddle, you assume that there is an unmovable object--again, this assumes that there is no unstoppable object otherwise how would you have an unmovable object? So when you assume both exist and ask what happens when they meet, you've contradicted yourself. There is the "paradox".

However, if you force such objects to meet, I do like the simple solution of @WetSavannaAnimal that the unstoppable object would just pass through the unmovable object. Hence, it has not been stopped and the unmovable object has not been moved.

Comment: Okay. But, were you trying to say something at the last? *"Hence, it has not been sto"* I think you didn't complete ;-)

Comment: The page refreshed itself and the line must have been lost! But it's fixed now!

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like dark matter colliding with an asteroid to me;-)
In this case they move through each other afar as I know.

Comment: Both an asteroid and dark matter (if it exists) are physical objects with finite mass, and therefore do not apply to the OP's scenario.

Answer (score -5):

So, I believe the answer (from the youtube video) is they will just pass right through each other.

Now that wasn't so hard was it...

Comment: I regret to inform you that that youtube video in no way contains any real physics. It's just popular scientific 'braintertainment' speculation. Your question is simply ill-defined and not really meaningful in physics.

Comment: This can't be an "answer" because the question is ill-defined and involves infinities, which makes it non-physical.

Comment: I'm happy to take the hit and not delete the question, but I have learnt that physics overflow isn't for a laugh, even if its a good laugh. Although I suspect its less that there isn't fun to have, but more that my idea of fun compared with physicist is far removed. So you have my apologies, but I'll leave this here incase another like me has the bright idea to ask this question :)