# About how much force would something have to exert to be effectively unstoppable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, kinematics

Assuming an object is moving in a straight line propelled by a force. How much energy would that force have to exert so that there are no known forces or objects that could stop it from moving in that straight line?

I'd guess limits like the speed of light might come into play here, but it would be interesting to know what the values would be if those limits weren't there.

Comment: I can always counter your phantasmagorical unstoppable force with an equally phantasmagorical immovable object. You have to give us a little more than this to have a useful physics question. Can the matter inside a neutron star stop any conventional projectile? Of course it can. Can a black hole absorb a neutron star? Yep.

Comment: I guess let's use the neutron star then if that's the stand in for the immovable object. How much energy would it take to move a 1kg ball through it in a straight line?

Comment: @finglonger None. The ball will splat on the surface at energies far less that that required to send even 1 proton through a neutron star

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80956/2451

Comment: If you wanted to move anything "trough" a neutron star, you would basically have to invest its entire binding energy, which is probably in the 10^47J range, or so. At the end there would be no neutron star left. You may end up with a black hole, if you actually tried that, though...

Comment: Or another Big Bang

Comment: Nope. See, now we are getting phantasmagorical, after all.

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you! I'm sorry for the badly formed question. Questions like this usually just stop at such and such is impossible, but I was kind of just looking for a number if it wasn't. Physics seems to assume things frictionless environments in some cases, not sure why assuming a black hole didn't form is invalid.

Comment: This question was closed as opinion-based. But given that the answer is "something can't be unstoppable", that seems pretty definitive and not opinion-based to me. Perhaps that wasn't a valid close reason?

Answer (score 5):

This is unphysical. There is no force or momentum that would make something unstoppable. First of all, any moving object can be made to diverge from a straight line path simply by applying a small force perpendicular to its motion. Secondly, no matter how large a momentum an object has, it can be completely halted by a similar object with the same momentum travelling the opposite direction.

That said, being "unstoppable" is possible within physics. Massless particles travel at the speed of light and, as such, they are not at rest in any frame. Therefore, they can be called "unstoppable" in so far as they are never observed as unmoving or stopped.

But in short, nothing in physics is unstoppable as you describe it.

Actually, let me expand on that point a bit more. When you discuss barriers, opposing forces, the energy needed to punch through something, etc., you are always referring to momentum. Momentum is key. Give a proton the same momentum as an asteroid and it will have the same devastating impact when it hits something (but an asteroid always looks cooler doing it). An object's momentum translates easily to its kinetic energy and the force it can apply to a target. However, **there is no upper limit on momentum**. This means that there is no extremes for the value of force or kinetic energy. There are some extreme values for energy, above which owe have no sufficient understanding of the laws of physics. But all forms of matter you are used to and would want to talk about cease to exist at these energy levels.

So let me be as clear as possible, things cannot be even "effectively" unstoppable. If we ignore the fact that anything with mass has a rest frame where it is stopped, then we have to acknowledge the fact that absolutely any object can be effectively stopped by something else with equal or greater momentum.

Want to fire a 1kg rock at practically the speed of light (say $v=c(1-10^{-60})$)? Go for it. That will give it a kinetic energy of around $7\times10^{29}$ Joules, which is more energy than the Sun outputs in an hour. But will that make it unstoppable? Nope. Let's put a neutron star in its path. That rock is going to stop. Why? First, in the rock's frame of reference, the neutron star is coming at it at that same, ridiculous speed and like a freight train hitting a flea, it won't feel a thing. Second, in the star's reference frame, the mass of the star is so large that the transfer of momentum would make it move at only a few millimetres a second (impressive nonetheless).

Every example you can think of, all it requires to stop an object cold is another object with similar or greater momentum blocking it. And since there is no upper limit on momentum, nothing can ever even be "effectively" unstoppable

Comment: Sorry for the badly formed question! "Effectively" was what I was trying to get at. The "straight line" test was my (bad) attempt at getting there. Assuming something has mass and could potentially be stopped, I was wondering about numbers out at the extremes of known forces, barriers, etc. Can we know the energy levels it would take to overcome them directly without failing off into "at this point there's some fundamental extreme in observed physics and something weird happens"?